# Quick De Moivre's Theorem Question/Example

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

[image]

Could these also be solutions since 4 is even? 
[image]

I am relatively new to complex bases and fractional powers.

[image]

Comment: You're measure it twice

Comment: Compare $k_2$ with the first component of your second answer, so $-1.172 - 0.334i$ to $-(1.172+0.334i)$ (and the rest of course).

Comment: I didn't catch that when I wrote the question. Thanks for your help!